# Removing element from original numpy array passed to function

Tags: python, numpy

I got this function that I'm trying to rewrite using numpy arrays as speed is critical here. However, since appending and removing elements from a numpy array only returns a new array, the original arrays passed to the function won't be affected as with list.append() and list.remove(). Is there any way to get around this?

```
def flood(p, groups, p_a, g):
    if p in p_a:
       groups.append((p, g))
       p_a.remove(p)
       flood((p[0]-1, p[1]), groups, p_a, g)
       flood((p[0]+1, p[1]), groups, p_a, g)
       flood((p[0], p[1]+1), groups, p_a, g)
       flood((p[0], p[1]-1), groups, p_a, g)
```

Comment: Someone smarter than me may come along and correct me.  But the reason Numpy is able to be so fast is that all of its arrays have a fixed size and memory.  It can't both be fast and allow what you want.

Comment: Even if you were to convert this to use numpy arrays, you woudln't get any speed benefits because of the amount of Python code executed in the recursion.  You have to approach it as operations on the array as a whole.  Perhaps if you provide an example of the input and expected output we could suggest an appropriate array oriented solution

Comment: Function code like this is meaningless without some sample arguments.  While we can guess `groups` and `p_a` are lists, but lists can contain anything.  In any case, this does not look like a function that can be rewritten to use `numpy`. As you say, arrays don't grow/shrink like lists. Also iteration through arrays is slower.

Comment: @FrankYellin That explains a lot, actually. I thought about this for a while and came up with a another way to do this, or so I think. Thanks.

Comment: Does Numba could be an answer?

Comment: How much time have you spent reading the `numpy` `absolute_beginners` documentation?

Comment: @hpchavaz, why `numba`? Mostly it's used to speed up `numpy` calculations, not list stuff.

Comment: @hpaulj 'mostly' but may be not only

Comment: It's not clear what this code is supposed to do, since there's no data. Please take a look at [minimum working examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)